# How to dynamically instantiate a more specific type in a linq query

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, instantiation

I have a linq query that is currently doing an object instantiation based on a generic type parameter.  I actually need to instantiate a more specific subclass of the generic parameter.  Is there a way to do the instantiation with a derived type?  I'm open to using reflection or even direct IL emit if necessary, though I'd like to try and keep type checking on the base class's properties if possible.

So the code I have is like this:

```
IQueryable<TType> myObjects = from blah in blahblah
                              select new TType
                              {
                                   PropertyA = someValue;
                                   PropertyB = someOtherValue;
                              }
```

But I need the objects in the IQueryable to actually be a derived class from TType.  I don't know in advance which derived class they will be, just that they will all be the same derived type based on some other logic.

Comment: Is `TType` an actual type or a template parameter?  If it's a template parameter can you add the constraint on `TType`?

Comment: TType is a generic type parameter on the class containing the method.  The goal of the code is to produce a context specific entity from a common base type.  We can only guarantee at compile time that it will be the some derivative of the abstract common type.

Comment: How can you guarantee that at compile time?  Are there any constraints or could it be any type?  Could it be an `int`, for example?

Comment: Could one of the parameters to the function be a `Func<TType> constructor` that returns a newly constructed object that is some type of `TType`?  Then you could pass in anything from `()=> new ConcreteType()` to `() =>  MyFactory.Create(...)`.

Comment: @DStanley-TType is where constrained to the abstract common base type.

Comment: @Servy - that's an interesting idea.  I might be able to use that to offload the reflection that I'd need to generate the object to code handled by my framework.

Comment: So something like `where TType : BaseType`?

Comment: @DStanley - correct, TType is constrained to a base type and the actual result will be a collection of a type directly derived from whatever value TType has.  So types are CommonAbstractBaseType, CaseABaseType:CommonAbstractBaseType, CaseBBaseType:CommonAbstractBaseType, MoreSpecificAbstractType:CommonAbstractBaseType, CaseAMoreSpecificType:MoreSpecificAbstractType, CaseBMoreSpecificType:MoreSpecificAbstractType

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need a Factory pattern:

```
from blah in blahblah
select BaseTypeFactory.Create(/* parameters/objects necessary to create the BaseType*/)
```

The `BaseTypeFactory` would then do whatever it needs to do to spit out the correct derived `BaseType` instances.

If (as your comments say) `TType` is constrained to a particular base type, the Factory could look something like:

(assuming `TType` is constrained by `where TType : BaseType`)

```
public void BaseType TTypeFactory.Create(/* parameters/objects needed to create Base Types*/)
{
    // full of assumptions, modify to fit your needs:
    switch( typeID /*or some othervariable designating type to create*/)
    case 1: // DerivedType 1
        return new DerivedType1 { /* initialization parameters */ };
        break;
    case 2:
        return new DerivedType2 { /* initialization parameters */ };
        break;
    // etc.

}
```

Comment: But since TType is a generic parameter, not a known compile time type, there's no way of ensuring that it has a static `Create` method.

Comment: Yeah, I've been working in that direction too.  The trick is that the particular construction is specific to the given LINQ query and the determination of the appropriate type requires a Reflection call which I'm trying to avoid the end user having to write.  I might be able to have them use a base construction though and then set the values they need to on the object that is returned to them.

Comment: @Servy - Since I know that TType must be a derivation of a particular type, I can have it call a factory for that base type and completely ignore the generic parameter.  I will know that the factory will always produce a derivative of TType so therefore it should be safe for me to cast the result back to TType and thus satisfy the generic constraint.  At least I think that will work.

Comment: @AJHenderson I thought `TType` was the base type, not the derived type.  If it's the derived type why can't you just use the code in the OP and tack on a `where T : new()` clause?

Comment: @Servy - you are correct, TType is the base type.  But I can cast a derived type to the base type.  The problem that I just realized this leaves me with though is how the factory can behave correctly for multiple levels of inheritance.  For example, if TType was BaseCommon, then it would make CaseABase or CaseBBase objects, but if it was DerivedCommon (derived from BaseCommon) then it would make CaseADerivedCommon or CaseBDerivedCommon.

Comment: @DStanley - That is actually almost exactly what my factory methods look like (currently they live as a static method on the base type).  The problem is that without reflection I can't call the correct factory since the logic is different depending on what the value of TType is.  Ie, if TType is CommonBase at run time, case 1 returns caseACommon, but if TType is MoreSpecificBase at run time then case 1 returns CaseAMoreSpecific.  A method for preventing the developer writing the projection from having to deal with the reflection would be preferable.

Comment: Then use reflection and/or pass more context into your `Create` method.

Comment: I ended up going a different route to sidestep the problem by introducing some different limitations to the behavior of the code, but I think this answer is probably near the closest we can get.  Thanks to both you and Servy.